# Which one execute first?

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('mousedown',(function(){
        console.log('code');
    }));
</script>
<input id="btn" type="button" onmousedown="console.log('button')">
```

Which one will execute first and why?

Comment: Could you not add an different alert for each one and see what pops up first?

Comment: Looks like you've got everything there to determine it on your own. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I wonder if this is well-defined in the specification or if it is entirely browser-dependent.

Comment: In Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04, it's the [inline JavaScript first, and then the code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KGe5z/). This is with slightly corrected html, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inline script executes, `document.getElementById('btn')` evaluates to `null`, and a `TypeError` is thrown.

Then your `input` tag fails to parse.

But let’s pretend you add a closing `"` to the `onmousedown` attribute and order the `script` element after the `input` element. Then you would see

```
button
code
```

because the events execute in the order they’re defined in.

Comment: Documentation reference? The "onmousedown" isn't "added", but "set" -- there can be multiple attached events, but only one "onmousedown". The question is then, is this order *guaranteed between* these two different kinds of event handlers? And if so, by whom?

Comment: @pst, excellent question: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html section 1.3.2

Comment: @davin Of course: "In order to achieve compatibility with HTML 4.0, implementors *may view the setting of attributes which represent event handlers as the creation and registration of an EventListener* on the EventTarget." :)

Comment: @pst, Not sure what "may" means though. I.e. I'm not sure what degree of leniency is given to implementors to choose to do otherwise. I think there's an intro document somewhere that defines the degree of leniency of each term usage (I'm not a standards expert), but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @davin good point. The comment by David Thomas disagrees with the quote I extracted (I believe).

Comment: @pst, why? First the html+inline code is parsed and the "button" listener added, and then then js code, which adds the "code" listener. That order is the same as the spec's recommendation.